# Accessing redirect id from grails "after" filter

Tags: grails, redirect, filter

I have a standard grails (1.3.7) scaffolded controller save closure as follows:

```
    def save = {

        // ... instantiate and save "instance" ...

        redirect(action: "show", id: instance.id)
    }
```

... and an "after" filter, e.g.:

```
        def filters = 
{
    save(controller:'*', action:'save')
    {
        after =
        {
            // How do I get the newly created entity's ID here?     
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to access the new entity's ID within the filter for any controller, without having to add any extra/special code to every controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in the request as recommended by splix or consider using interceptors instead. In an 'afterInterceptor' you have direct access to the model. see [Controller Interceptors](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.5%20Controller%20Interceptors)

**Updated**
Based on your comments, you could use meta-programming techniques and intercept each 'afterInsert' call on domain classes. For example, if you add this in your Bootstrap:

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass gc ->
    gc.metaClass.afterInsert = {
        println "$id"
    }
}
```

you should be able to access all newly created domains objects and perform common operations.

Comment: I've updated my question - I want to do some processing for newly created entities (i.e. update search index) across all controllers.  In other words, I need to access model but all do it in a more filter like context, since it needs to be applied to all controllers.

Answer (score 3):

You can put it into `request`, like

```
request.setAttribute('CREATED_ID', instance.id)
```

and get at filter as

```
def id = request.getAttribute('CREATED_ID')
```

---

Update:

Or you also put it into request at `beforeInsert` event, or at your own event listener: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Comment: This answer is correct for my original question, however I've since updated the question after reviewing and releasing that my question wasn't specific enough.

Comment: thanks for the answers, but if I understand correctly, the solution in your update shifts the problem from customising each controller to "customising" each domain class.  The thing is, the id is being passed in to the redirect, e.g. "redirect(action: "show", id: instance.id)", in each scaffolded controller - is this accessible somehow from after filter?  This would mean minimal coding and clutter in controller/domain classes.

Comment: You can make _one_ event listener, for all domains. see link

Comment: Even in plain old hibernate. I'm talking about hibernate event listeners. I see that this dsl is introduced only in grails 2.0, but you always can used it directly. See hbernate docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html